# How to insert database rows if there are no answers

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am trying to insert each answer for each question in the database. Problem is that there is a possibility that a question may have no answers, so I tried the code below but it does not insert a db row if a question has no answer, what I was trying to do is that if no answer then display the string `No Answer` under the `Answer` column for that question:

```
 $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

if( $insert && $insertanswer)
{

    $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);
    $question_ids = array();

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
    {

... //Question INSERT goes here

        $questionId = $mysqli->insert_id;

            $question_ids[$questionNo] = $questionId;

}

        $results = $_POST['value'];
        foreach($results as $id => $value) 
        {
            $answer = $value;

            $quesid = (int)$question_ids[$id];   

            foreach($value as $answer) 
            {

            if($answer == '' || $answer === null){
                $answer = 'No Answer';
            }

                $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);

                $insertanswer->execute();

                if ($insertanswer->errno) {
                    // Handle query error here
                    echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
                    break 7;
                }
            }
        }


    //close your statements at the end


    $insertanswer->close();

}
```

The `['value']` comes from an input:

```
var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');
```

Below is the SHOW CREATE TABLE for the `Answer` Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Answer` (
 `AnswerId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `QuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `Answer` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AnswerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Below is a var dump where if I set question 1 to have answers `B` and `C`, question 2 to have no answers, question 3 to have answer `B` and question 4 to have no answer, it outputs the following from var dump:

```
var_dump($question_ids);
    var_dump($results);


array(4) { 
[1]=> int(265) 
[2]=> int(266) 
[3]=> int(267) 
[4]=> int(268) 
} 
[1]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> string(1) "B" 
[1]=> string(1) "C" 
} 
[3]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> string(1) "B" 
}
```

So it outputs those set of answers in questions 1 and 3. But does not post `No Answer` for question 2 and 4.

If all questions had an answer as thisL

```
question 1: B C
question 2: A
question 3: B
question 4: A C
```

Then the var dump displays this in var dump:

```
array(4) { 
[1]=> int(277) 
[2]=> int(278) 
[3]=> int(279) 
[4]=> int(280) 
} 
array(4) { 
[1]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> string(1) "B" 
[1]=> string(1) "C" } 
[2]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> string(1) "A" 
} 
[3]=> array(1) 
{ 
[0]=> string(1) "B" 
} 
[4]=> array(2) 
{ 
[0]=> string(1) "A" 
[1]=> string(1) "C" 
} }}
```

As you can see for each question is inserts the relevant answers. So the issu is if the question has no answers that it does not insert a db row and state `No Answer`. My question is how to include a `No Answer`for each question in the db that has no answers selected in those questions?

Comment: Another bounty with cheated timeout on cheated reputation points. Why am I not surprised?

Comment: Fake user, fake reputation...

Comment: How can you tell that the rep points/user are fake?

Comment: Well, the username is a dead giveaway, but I also wonder what 'fake' reputation entails.

Comment: In answer to my own question, this probably, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76356/does-stackoverflow-prevent-cheating-with-fake-accounts

Answer (score 4):

Simply do not insert anything into `Answer` table when there is no answer. Rest of your solution is basically correct.

When displaying questions with answer, check if there is answer (empty select result or null in left joined column) to show and if not, show "No answer". But there is no "No answer" in database.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code on what you mean? you see the problem is that if I execute INSERT, the problem is that it insert all answers in its questions but does not insert anything in Answer table if question as no answer. How will it be able to refer back to those questions has no answers to insert the correct questionid's in Answer Table?

Answer (score 1):

When your code get to `$results = $_POST['value'];`, `$question_ids` is populated with the ids of questions that must be included in the table.

My suggestion is to remove elements from this array right after including the first answer to the related question. This way, after the `foreach($results as $id => $value)` loop, this array will contain only questions without explicit answers. The next step is just to include these pseudo-answer "No answer" in the DB.

The relevant code for you (inserted lines are //* commented):

```
$notAnswered = $question_ids; //* Make a copy
$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach ($results as $id => $value) {
    $answer = $value;
    $quesid = (int)$question_ids[$id];
    $pos = array_search($quesid, $notAnswered); //* Search for it
    if ($pos !== false) //* It's in the array
        array_splice($notAnswered, $pos, 1); //* Delete it from the array
    foreach ($value as $answer) {
        $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);
        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
            // Handle query error here
            echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
            break 7;
        }
    }
}

//* Insert 'No Answer' for each question not answered
foreach ($notAnswered as $id) {
    $insertanswer->bind_param('is', $id, 'No Answer');
    $insertanswer->execute();
    if ($insertanswer->errno) {
        // Handle query error here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
        break 7;
    }
}

// Close your statements at the end
$insertanswer->close();
```

One important thing to note here: array_splice is *very* slow in PHP for big arrays (>100 elements). But I don't think this is the case here.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I tested it but it is still doing same thing, it is not displaying No Answer if user does not select an answer. It is still ignoring inserting those non answer rows in db

Comment: Can you please post the `var_dump($notAnswered)` right before each `foreach` loop?

Comment: var dump for not answer shows this if you follow scenario for the first var dump in my question: `array(2) { [0]=> int(309) [1]=> int(312) } `

Comment: It might have done it now, I will just test it again, I think you can't put 'No Answer' straight in the `bind_param()`, put it in a variable `$noanswer = 'No Answer';` and put `$noanswer` in `bind_param()`

Comment: Major problem, it is attaching `no answer` at end of some answers,so for example is doing `B,C,No Answer`, I think it is only attaching to multiple answers